# CMSampleBuffer samples values

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to access samples for further processing (visual mostly) from `CMSampleBuffer`, here is my code:

```
 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList()
    var blockBuffer : CMBlockBuffer?

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, nil, &audioBufferList, MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size, nil, nil, 0, &blockBuffer)

    let buffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &audioBufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers))

    var data  =  audioBufferList.mBuffers.mData

    let pointer = data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)

    let floatPointer = data?.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: 1024)
    let floatBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: floatPointer, count: 1024)
    let outputArray = Array(floatBuffer)
    print(outputArray[0..<20])

}
```

I am getting the results but they seems like in the strange (for me) kind of form, like this (output from print statement):

```
[-snan(0x1dff94), -nan(0x15ffba), 2.93871626e-39, 2.29594486e-39, 8.26537682e-40, -nan(0x1affef), -nan(0xeffe0), 2.84690739e-39, 4.95919386e-39, 4.86737658e-39, 1.19389788e-39, -nan(0x8ffe4), -snan(0xaffa6), -3.29645785e+38, -snan(0x17ff85), -nan(0x5ffae), 2.66320417e-39, 2.11228928e-39, -nan(0x2fff6), -nan(0x19ffd6)]
[-2.45903224e+38, -3.13694095e+38, -snan(0xdff85), -nan(0xbffb4), -snan(0x11ffba), -2.83122967e+38, -2.41915276e+38, -2.67170487e+38, -2.83122724e+38, -2.73817357e+38, -2.39257084e+38, -1.50864781e+38, -1.34249056e+38, -1.71464408e+38, -2.53878186e+38, -2.48561761e+38, -2.64512051e+38, -3.19011393e+38, -snan(0x12ff96), -snan(0x1bffb7)]
```

The question is how can I access `CMSampleBuffer` samples in the way that "normal" `AVAudioPCMBuffer`?

`FloatChannelData` Or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` the samples I get are `Int16`s (not sure if you *can* configure for `Float`s), and when printed with your modified code, they make perfect sense:

```
let intPointer = data?.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: 1024)
```

Is the audio `Int16`ness documented anywhere? If not you can always inspect the sample buffer's format by looking at its `AudioStreamBasicDescription`

```
let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)!)!.pointee
```

or start using swift 4 for a slightly more readable

```
let asbd = sampleBuffer.formatDescription!.audioStreamBasicDescription!.pointee
```